# Why week of year is wrong?

Tags: datetime, calendar, formatting, time

I'm using this code :

```
Time t = Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(Date.parse('22/02/2016'), t);
system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, Integer.valueof(dt.Format('w')));
```

It returns `9` but if I check in Salesforce calendar, the February 22nd corresponds to week `8`.

Can someone explain me why ?

**EDIT**

It seems there is a bug with this method. I try the following code :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(2016, 1, 8);
String tz = 'Europe/Paris';
system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, Integer.valueof(dt.Format('w', tz)));
```

It returns `2` but in the calendar for this time zone (Salesforce calendar for example) the week number is `1`.

I don't know what I can do with this !

Comment: If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00).So if you see 1 Jan 2016 is on friday so it will still be 52nd or 53rd week of previous year.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be related to your timezone settings.

Look - I have faced similar issues before.

Look to my ideas:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnP9AAK
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnHPAA0

I guess you might need to use FormatGMT instead of Format method.

================

When I try to run your code under US-local settings, I get the error:

```
System.TypeException: Invalid date: 22/02/2016
```

Which means, you must have European local settings if your code works for you.

When I change your code to

```
Time t = Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(Date.parse('02/22/2016'), t);
//DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(Date.parse('22/02/2016'), t);
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Integer.valueof(dt.Format('w')));
```

It returns me 9.

===================

I think it should be 9.

Look:

1 Jan 1-2

2 Jan 3-9

3  Jan 10-16

4 Jan 17-23

5 Jan 24-30

6  Jan 31 - Feb 6

7 Feb 7-13

8 Feb 14-20

9 Feb 21-27

10 28 - Mar 5

22 of Feb falls into 9th week.

==========================

Note that this really depends on your locale.

If I add additional debug monitoring dt itself

```
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, dt);
```

if would result into a different dates.
Like

```
2016-02-22 17:00:00
```

on NY time or

```
2016-02-22 10:00:00
```

on Ukraine time, so if you go enough to some bias (like New Zealand +13 or Samoa -11) you might get some unexpected results.

Comment: Yes, but normally it will returns 8 ! Check SF calendar. This week is the 8th week of year. And it's the same with `formatGMT()`.

Comment: are you referring to some standard SalesForce page? could you please make a screenshot or give a link to that standard page?

Comment: It's in a custom page. But I try this code in Developer console to check why I didn't have the good week.

Comment: I think it should be 9.

Look:

1 Jan 1-2

2 Jan 3-9

3  Jan 10-16

4 Jan 17-23

5 Jan 24-30

6  Jan 31 - Feb 6

7 Feb 7-13

8 Feb 14-20

9 Feb 21-27

10 28 - Mar 5

Could you please should the code which return 8?

Comment: 28 dec 2015 to 2 jan 2016 will be 1st week.So it will come as 9.

Comment: Yes, in US locale, but European should be 8. I need to modify my code. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertBarnett looks like he's right to me. First week in January was Friday 1st to Sunday 3rd, depending which day you count as the end of the week.

Comment: In Salesforce calendar, with US locale, this week is 9. With EU locale, this week is 8. I need to find how use locale to get the good week.

Comment: Can you add a link to the Salesforce calendar where it says that?

Comment: `/00U/c?cType=1&md2=8&md0=2016` : with EU locale, in week view, Salesforce calendar shows 22/02 to 28/02.
The same URL with US locale shows 2/14 to 2/20.